# ChartJS + twig symfony

Tags: javascript, arrays, symfony, chart.js

I've got an issue, I'm trying to create a chart (pie) with ChartJS using twig data.

The chart label uses an array, so I'm giving a twig array to it like this :

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ({{array|json_encode()|raw}})
```

But it displays "object Object". For my purpose I want to display an attribute of that object, in that example : "intitule"

[image: My array]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you write an own [Twig extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) and add a filter function to it:

**1. Create the extension class** and add a filter with name `chart`:

```
// src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('chart', array($this, 'chartFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function chartFilter($items, $key = 'intitule')
    {
        $output = [];
        foreach ($items as $item {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $item)) {
                $output[] = $item[$key];
            }   
        }    

        return json_encode($output));
    }
}
```

**2. Create service**

Depending on your [services.yml](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html#register-an-extension-as-a-service) definition you may need to create a service for the extension:

```
app.twig_extension:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

**3. Use the filter in your view**

you can use the filter using it like this:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ({{array|chart|raw}})
```